# terraform with gcp provider fails in apply due to some authentication error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

i have a simple code which creates VPC on google cloud but when i apply then it throws an error  oauth2: cannot fetch token:
I had created a service account and assigned it editor role to project,Network,Compute Engine, service account token and service account admin. Created a key and downloaded it's json.
I feel i might have missed something which i'm not able to figure out.

here's my code

````
  credentials = file("poc-dev-terrafrom-0ea89j6c1fce.json")
  project     = "dev-terrafrom"
  region      = "us-central1"
}
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "GCPvpc"
  project = "dev-terrafrom "
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges" {
  name          = "test-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/26"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link
}

upon apply get below error
  Enter a value: yes

google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creating...

Error: Error creating Network: Post https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/dev-terrafrom%20/global/networks?alt=json: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

  on vpc.tf line 1, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network":
   1: resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {```
````

Comment: Are you running Terraform through a proxy?

Comment: no not using any proxy plain simple code like pasted here and have downloaded json key from service account 
```* provider.google: version = "~> 3.5"
* provider.template: version = "~> 2.1"```   same machine i use for aws & azure it works fine this is first time i'm working on gcp

Comment: It looks like something is mitm'ing your connection and presenting a certificate that your trust store doesn't trust. The other alternative is you are running in an environment with a restricted set of CA certificates which isn't including Google's API endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

It was my linux machines issue i changed my environment and then the code worked just fine,it's  weird that why the machine acted so differently for diff provider.

```
data.template_file.credfile: Refreshing state...
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creating...
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creation complete after 20s [id=projects/development-terrafrom/global/networks/myvpc]
google_compute_subnetwork.network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges: Creating...
google_compute_subnetwork.network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_subnetwork.network-with-private-secondary-ip-ranges: Creation complete after 17s [id=projects/dev-terrafrom/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/test-subnetwork]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```